# Ruby's Paper Trail expansion of association data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the airblade Paper Trail gem in my Ruby project, i'm trying to use it more of a what happened when history than a versioning history - that is, I am not going to try and recreate data from the version history, more use it to tell users what happened along the lifetime of a record.

Is there a way I can add a custom dumper or hook to my models that will allow any associations eg company_id to get traversed to a meaningful value - eg company name.

Take the model Company with attribute 'name' which is related to Product through id.

When product gets updated, company_id gets stored in the version history, what i'd like to do is get it to traverse the relationship just prior to saving and get me the company name.

I found reference to calls to 'dump' in the code but i'm wondering how I could extend my models to respond to 'dump' correctly.